# Typecasting structure pointer to character pointer

Tags: c

I have structure defined as

```
typedef struct Check
{     
    char conn_type;  
    int fd;
 }Check;
 Check *msg;
 //malloc code not writing.Consider it as malloced.
 msg->con_type = 1;
 msg->fd = listen_fd = 10;
add_select_msg_com_con((char*)msg);
```

I saw somewhere in code , they were typecasting it as (char *)Check

eg -

add_select((char*)msg)

In its definnation

```
void add_select(char* data_ptr)
{
    struct epoll_event pfd
    pfd.data.ptr = (void *) data_ptr;
 }
```

I want to know , where ptr in pfd.data.ptr is void pointer  how it will get value of ptr as connection type.
How it works?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like it might be a partial hangover from pre-standard C, where there was no `void *` type and `char *` was used as the universal pointer type instead.

Comment: Your question lack information. You can't cast like that. Further `Check` doesn't exist. And you write `check` one place and `Check`another. Please provide the actual code and all code needed to understand it.

Comment: I noticed your update. But the code is still incomplete. You must show how `Check` is defined. It has nothing to do with `struct Check` - the `typedef` is wrong.

Comment: @4386427 while you're at it a semicolon is missing after `struct epoll_event pfd`

Answer (score 3):

Ok let's define a structure properly (yours is anonymous but I assume it is a typo):

```
typedef struct 
{     
    char conn_type;  
    int fd;
 } Check;
```

now in the sender's code I define & initialize a variable of type `Check` called `msg`.

```
Check msg = {'a',12};
```

I want to send an event with the contents of `msg`, using a library that does not know `Check`. I create a pointer on `char` and take reference of `msg`

```
char *pmsg = (char*)&msg;
```

Then I call

```
add_select(pmsg);
```

They cast as `char *` so it fits the prototype of `add_select` (it doesn't change the value of the pointer, but it's type so the compiler accepts it)

In `add_select` it is cast again as `void *` (which is unnecessary since `void *` is the generic pointer type) which is the generic pointer to pass user-data in messages within a framework that is not aware of your `Check` structure (the `epoll_event` structure has a "user data" `void *` pointer used to pass any information to the event listener)

I would rather define `add_select` like this:

```
void add_select(void* data_ptr)
{
    struct epoll_event pfd;
    pfd.data.ptr = data_ptr;
 }
```

So I can call it directly with the `msg` variable, no need to cast:

```
add_select(&msg);
```

#### now on the message reception side

The program (event listener) that gets the message (on the other end of the transmission) has to know that the anonymous byte-stream message hides a `Check` structure to perform the reverse cast:

```
// convert/map the anonymous data to a `Check` structure
Check *recieved_msg = (Check *)pfd.data.ptr;
```

so it can access `recieved_msg->conn_type` etc...

Comment: thanks.but one thing i want to know , little bit new to typecsting, what happens while typecasting structure to character pointer .

Comment: I want to clear 2 doubts: 1) what happens when we typecas structure to character pointer as we did in the first method .2) In second, when we typecast  pfd.data.ptr as  (*(char *)pfd.data.ptr, how it is giving the vale of connection type

Comment: the cast is just to tell the compiler to accept the pointer type. And on the reciever side, the reciever has to know which type is behind the array of bytes, or it's not possible to decode the message.